# this.props.history.push not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate using history push inside App.jsx.
I have used below code for the same.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        if(!this.authService.isAuthenticated())
        {           
             this.props.history.push('/Login');
        }
    }
```

But it is giving an error as history is undefined.
I tried logging props object and I got the below output.

[image]

Please help me in navigating inside app.jsx.

Comment: you have to use `withRouter` while exporting this component

Comment: Can you explain why you think the history prop should be there in the first place?

Comment: Are you passing history prop to Router like this <Router history={history}> ???

Answer (score 1):

Export your component with `withRouter`.

import withRouter.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
```

Export in your component like this.

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent)//your component name
```

Comment: refer here for more about `withRouter` -> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md